# How can I soft-wrap a word to a new line?

Tags: wrapping, line-breaks, multiple-lines

Using textwidth (tw=74) a word will be moved to the next line (with an indent usually) with a newline character at the end of the line avoiding over-length. This is a hard wrap, and resizing the window will not change the location of the wrap. Using `:set wrap`, soft wrapping sends the text that would fall off the right side of the window to the next line instead, keeping all of a line's text visible. I'd like to combine some of each function, such that a word moves entirely to the next line after a certain point, but does not get permanently sent there in the file with a newline character.

It doesn't matter if this sending to the next line occurs only immediately after a string broaching the set number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `'linebreak'` option:

```
:set linebreak
```

See `:help 'linebreak'` for details, including the use of `'breakat'`, `'breakindent'`, and `'showbreak'`.