# Wrap lines only after a space

Tags: neovim

So, I like that (n)vim has line wrapping support, but what I dislike about it is that it does things like this:

```
 1 | Instead of wrapping text--|
 2 | like this, Vim does it lik|
 3 | e this.                   |
```

How could I make (n)vim wrap text after whitespaces, and not deliberately after any character it finds?

Also, I am talking about the screen wrapping, not the auto-wrapping it can do by inserting a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following question answer yours [How can I soft-wrap a word to a new line?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15717/how-can-i-soft-wrap-a-word-to-a-new-line)

The author proposes you to use option `linebreak`:

```
set linebreak
```